# How move current line to top of the window with `scrolloff` set

Tags: scrolling

I want to scroll the current line to be the topmost line in the window, even with `scroloff` set.

How do I do this?

I want to use it with:

```
com! TestColours :echo "Please wait..." | :so /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/colortest.vim | normal 8G{{move line to top of screen}}
```

Comment: Well, the whole point of `scrolloff` is *precisely* to prevent `zt` and other commands to reach the top and bottom of the window so… you'll have to unset it.

Comment: @romainl It's reasonable to want zt to ignore scrolloff while all the "other commands" respect it.

Comment: @Rich It's even more reasonable to fix the "other commands" to respect `scrolloff`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura That's the default behaviour.

Comment: Edited question to remove reference to `zt`.

Comment: Edited answer to provide a solution that doesn't change behaviour of zt ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the goal is simply to place line 8 at the top of the window, you can achieve this in the command line with:

```
:execute "normal gg7\<c-e>"
```

This jumps to the top of the file, and then scrolls down 7 lines.

### Update

Further to discussions in the comments, in order to create a `zT` mapping that moves the current line to the top of the window *without* using the `<c-e>` normal mode command, you can do this:

```
:nnoremap zT :execute "normal! " . (line(".") + &scrolloff) . "Gzt"<cr>
```

### Old answer

The below was written when the question implied the user wanted to change the behaviour of '`zt`' Not removing it, because it includes some useful features of Vimscript.

You could achieve this by remapping 'zt' to scroll the extra amount by using the normal mode `<c-e>` command with a count of `&scrolloff` after carrying out its usual behaviour:

```
:nnoremap zt zt:execute "normal!" . &scrolloff . "\<lt>c-e>\<lt>esc>"<cr>
```

Alternatively, if your goal is simply to move line 8 to the top of the window, and you don't want to change the behaviour of 'zt', you could instead change your command to:

```
... | execute "normal! " . (8 + &scrolloff) . "Gzt"
```

This places the cursor `&scrolloff` lines *below* line 8, and then performs a standard `zt`, moving line 8 to the top of the window.

Note that after using either solution, the line at the very top of the screen will no longer be the "current" line. This is impossible to achieve with `'scrolloff'` set, as that state is precisely what `'scrolloff'` is intended to prevent.

Comment: Both `zT` and `zB` are unmapped by default, so I used: `nnoremap zT zt:execute "normal!" . &scrolloff . "\<lt>C-e>\<lt>ESC>"<CR>` and `nnoremap zB zb:execute "normal!" . &scrolloff . "\<lt>C-y>\<lt>ESC>"<CR>`

Comment: I used the second form in the particular `!com` as per the question -- thanks!

Comment: @TomHale See my newest, much simpler answer if you don't actually need your new `zT` mapping for anything else.

Comment: How would you get the current line number in vim? Something like `&currentline`?

Comment: For finding the current line in Vimscript, you want, `line(".")`. `&option` gives you the value of a Vim option (the things you set with `:set`).

Comment: Neither `nnoremap zT execute "normal! " . (8 + &scrolloff) . "Gzt"` nor 
`nnoremap zT execute "normal! " . (line(".") + str2nr(&scrolloff)) . "Gzt"` works.

Are you sure your str2nr example is correct?

Comment: @TomHale The answers I've given definitely do what I've said they do in the answer, but possibly I've misunderstood what you're trying to achieve. What do you want your new `zT` mapping to do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43862/discussion-between-rich-and-tom-hale).